# Rotating only certain views specific ways when dealing with tab controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, model-view-controller, view

I have a tab bar controller with many (4) different views. I want to be able to rotate only one of my views to landScapeRight or LandscapeLeft (so no portrait or upside down). The others should only be portrait or upside down. I read somewhere that for tab controllers, all subviews needed to return YES in the method shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation: I have done this and everything works but I can only seem to get it in an all-or-nothing situation, meaning its either all of them do all the rotations or none rotate at all.
If anyone has any ideas or suggestions on how to tackle this problem, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Edit (I had misread your question): I don't think you can rotate subviews independently.

Comment: Are you sure of this Clafou? I'm just making sure so I don't waste my time trying to figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: I mean, I don't believe you can get the automatic (and animated) rotation behaviour that you can get for free when you change the device's orientation in anything but an all-or-nothing way. You can always rotate individual views yourself through their transform properties, for example `subView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2);`

Comment: Also, autorotate resizes the view it rotates, so you'd have to do any necessary resizing of the subviews yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a subclass of UITabBarController to get the autorotation behavior.  If you want to get independent rotation behavior, you'll have to go the affine transform route.  It's kind of a pain, but doable.

Comment: How much of a pain and is it less of a pain than making a seperate view for a landscape roation and another for portrait? Thanks!

Comment: It's just a bit tedious.  My standard way of dealing with it is to register with the notification center to listen for `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`; often a good place to do this is in viewDidLoad; also remove the observer in viewDidUnload in this case.  Then I implement a `receivedRotate:` callback to handle the orientation change. There you need to check the current orientation and apply a transform to the view as Clafou indicates; you also need to set the bounds of the view so that they are correct for that orientation.